# Issue with downloaded apk generated via app bundle

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-app-bundle

I have uploaded the google app bundle to google play console for testing where it sends a download link for your app via mail to all the added testers accounts. I am facing a issue here. It looks like the assetBundle added in the streaming assets folder does not get copied with the generated apk while downloading the app. If I generate the apk from app bundle (.aab) locally via buildtool the asset bundles in the streaming assets gets copied to the generated apk.

Has any aware of this issue ? Is there a solution for this?

Comment: you mean to say that the files in your assets folder were not included?

Comment: What do you call the "asset bundles" and the "streaming assets"?